# CSV file with label

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, tf-idf, sklearn-pandas

As suggested here [Python Tf idf algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277926/python-tf-idf-algorithm) I use this code to get the frequency of words over a set of documents.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
import codecs

def tokenize(text):
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    stems = []
    for item in tokens: stems.append(PorterStemmer().stem(item))
    return stems

with codecs.open("book1.txt",'r','utf-8') as i1,\
        codecs.open("book2.txt",'r','utf-8') as i2,\
        codecs.open("book3.txt",'r','utf-8') as i3:
    # your corpus
    t1=i1.read().replace('\n',' ')
    t2=i2.read().replace('\n',' ')
    t3=i3.read().replace('\n',' ')

    text = [t1,t2,t3]
    # word tokenize and stem
    text = [" ".join(tokenize(txt.lower())) for txt in text]
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(text).todense()
    # transform the matrix to a pandas df
    matrix = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
    # sum over each document (axis=0)
    top_words = matrix.sum(axis=0).sort_values(ascending=False)

    top_words.to_csv('dict.csv', index=True, float_format="%f",encoding="utf-8")
```

With the last line, I create a csv file where are listed all words and their frequency. Is there a way to put a label to them, to see if a word belong only to the third document, or to all?
My goal is to delete from the csv file all the words that appear only in the 3rd document (`book3`)

Comment: You are missing a portion of the code in that answer, specifically the `tokenize()` function.

Comment: @Gabriel Right, sorry, I added it

Comment: You are still missing the `word_tokenize()` and `PorterStemmer()` imports. Please make sure your code runs, if it doesn't explain clearly what is going on and what you'd like it to do.

Comment: @Gabriel I was missing the imports, sorry

Comment: (Now you are adding imports that are not required: `csv` and `os`) If your goal is to remove all words that appear in the 3rd book, why read it in at all? Can you not simply dismiss it from the start? If so, why not?

Comment: Let's consider this example: book1 and book2 are two harry potter books, while book3 is wikipedia corpus. I think that to find which are the most specific words to harry potter, I need to analyze also another type of document, like wikipedia corpus. Doing that I will be able to find the words that are more relevant. Is this assumption wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) attribute to filter out your `top_words` in the third book from the `top_ words` in the entire corpus.

(For the example below I downloaded three random books from http://www.gutenberg.org/)

```
import codecs
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
# import nltk
# nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

def tokenize(text):
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    stems = []
    for item in tokens: stems.append(PorterStemmer().stem(item))
    return stems

with codecs.open("56732-0.txt",'r','utf-8') as i1,\
        codecs.open("56734-0.txt",'r','utf-8') as i2,\
        codecs.open("56736-0.txt",'r','utf-8') as i3:
    # your corpus
    t1=i1.read().replace('\n',' ')
    t2=i2.read().replace('\n',' ')
    t3=i3.read().replace('\n',' ')

text = [t1,t2,t3]
# word tokenize and stem
text = [" ".join(tokenize(txt.lower())) for txt in text]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(text).todense()
# transform the matrix to a pandas df
matrix = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
# sum over each document (axis=0)
top_words = matrix.sum(axis=0).sort_values(ascending=False)

# top_words for the 3rd book alone
text = [" ".join(tokenize(t3.lower()))]
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(text).todense()
matrix = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
top_words3 = matrix.sum(axis=0).sort_values(ascending=False)

# Mask out words in t3
mask = ~top_words.index.isin(top_words3.index)
# Filter those words from top_words
top_words = top_words[mask]

top_words.to_csv('dict.csv', index=True, float_format="%f",encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, is it correct (as I said in the other comment) that I analyze 3 documents but I consider the word of only 2 of them?

Comment: Seems reasonable at first glance.

Comment: How is possible that a word that doesn't appear in the text,  appears in the csv file?

Comment: The line text = [" ".join(tokenize(txt.lower())) for txt in text] truncates in a wrong way words: word such Hermione, becomes hermion that is completely different and wrong

Comment: That's part of your original question, I did not come up with that line. I'd check the `tokenize()` call to see what's going on. Perhaps this are hyphenated words?

Comment: I don't know why, but I think I have solved it replacing toxenize() with word_tokenize()

Comment: That's because you are not using the [PortStemmer](https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/) anymore.

Comment: Is that correct? I mean, am I obtaining a right application of the algorithm without PortStemmer?