# How to fit text data to a NaiveBayes classifier

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, naivebayes, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to classify text on the basis of some binary valued variable using the NaiveBayes classifier of the scikit learn library

`X_train` - training data

`y_train` - training labels

Both are of type 'Series'

```
NB_classifier = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(alpha = 0.1)
NB_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

then I got an error saying that classifier doesn't accept string values

> could not convert string to float:

On referring to a similar question on this forum I learned that we're supposed to encode the string using **LabelEncoder**
So I did the following

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(X_train)

NB_classifier = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(alpha = 0.1)

NB_classifier.fit(le.transform(X_train), y_train)
```

Then I got the following error

> Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:...

I've already tried reshaping `X_train`, `y_train` to a matrix

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think this has an answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277926/python-tf-idf-algorithm. You will need to transform your strings to numerical values not with label encoder, but with some sort of vectorizer/text feature extraction method. Try over here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction

Comment: CountVectorizer does the job